# Multiple-level mapping (or Tree Hierachy) with SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, mapping, recursive-query

My log table has data like this

```
====================
| src_ip | dest_ip |
====================
| ip01_1 | ip01_2  |
| ip01_1 | ip01_3  |
| ip01_2 | ip01_4  |
| ip01_4 | ip01_5  |
| ip02_1 | ip02_2  |
| ip02_2 | ip02_3  |
====================
```

My required output is a table which contains dest_ip and the first requesting ip.

For example,
* `ip01_4` (`dest_ip`) has `ip01_1` as its `first_src_ip` (`ip01_1 -> ip01_2 -> ip01_4`) 
* `ip01_5` (`dest_ip`) has `ip01_1` as its `first_src_ip` (`ip01_1 -> ip01_2 -> ip01_4 -> ip01_5`)

Is there any way to use a SQL Query to create a table like below ?

```
==========================
| first_src_ip | dest_ip |
==========================
| ip01_1       | ip01_2  |
| ip01_1       | ip01_3  |
| ip01_1       | ip01_4  |
| ip01_1       | ip01_5  |
| ip02_1       | ip02_2  |
| ip02_1       | ip02_3  |
==========================
```

I'm thinking of using self-join but the joining times cannot be fixed.

Comment: what is the logic of this output?

Comment: I have just updated the logic of output :)

Comment: If there is a maximum length to the sequence, you can use repeated joins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that supports three levels of separation between nodes, e.g. `ip1 -> ip2, ip2 -> ip3, ip3 -> ip4`:

```
WITH IPs AS (
  SELECT 'ip01_1' AS src_ip, 'ip01_2' AS dest_ip UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ip01_1', 'ip01_3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ip01_2', 'ip01_4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ip01_4', 'ip01_5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ip02_1', 'ip02_2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ip02_2', 'ip02_3'
), Hop1 AS (
  SELECT
    COALESCE(
      (SELECT MIN(ip2.src_ip) FROM IPs AS ip2
       WHERE ip.src_ip = ip2.dest_ip),
      src_ip
    ) AS src_ip,
    dest_ip
  FROM IPs AS ip
), Hop2 AS (
  SELECT
    COALESCE(
      (SELECT MIN(ip2.src_ip) FROM IPs AS ip2
       WHERE ip.src_ip = ip2.dest_ip),
      src_ip
    ) AS src_ip,
    dest_ip
  FROM Hop1 AS ip
)
SELECT *
FROM Hop2
ORDER BY src_ip;
```

Each of the CTEs looks for an association between the current `src_ip` and another `dest_ip` in the original IP address mappings.